# Is it possible to change the value of rthe Range Fuction in Python while it runs?

Tags: python, for-loop, input, range

Nerdy project alert!

I am trying to make a python coded version of the Deck of Many things from DND. It works beautifully except that I want to be able to allow players to draw more cards from the same deck after they've finished drawing.

My current model doesn't allow them to do that and resets the deck back to the pristine set every time.

I want to keep the same deck, and if Certain cards (the joker/fool) ect are drawn allow the player to draw more.

I've been able to get the cards like Jester to Shuffle in but I cannot seem to get the program to stop and allow me to continue. I've tried the Return function, but always get errors, like not in a loop.

```
# playerInput here is whatever number the players put in
#card13 contains all the cards from a deck of many things

for draw in range(playerInput):
    cardDrawn = random.choice(card13)
    print(cardDrawn)
    print()
    card13.remove(cardDrawn)

    if cardDrawn == (void):
        print("Your soul is sucked from your body. Draw no more cards")
        break

    if cardDrawn == (donjon):
        print("You are imprisoned in a location of the DM's choosing. Draw no more cards")
        break   

    elif cardDrawn == (skull):
        print("Refer to the DMG to see the Specter of Death's stats")
        print()

    elif cardDrawn == (fool):
        print("the card magically shuffles back into the deck.")
        print()
        card13.append(cardDrawn)

    elif cardDrawn == (jester):
        print("the card magically shuffles back into the deck.")
        print()
        card13.append(cardDrawn)

#for fool and jester I don't know how to get the card to keep drawing.
```

I am hoping to get a prompt at the end of the code that if Jester or fool are drawn it will give the player an option to draw more cards as long as there are still cards left in the deck.

thanks for the help this is one of my first programs so I apologize for the sloppy work.

Comment: `Return` is not a function. It is a statement *inside* functions used to return from them. As you don't have functions here, you can't use it

Answer (score 2):

This is where a `while` loop is useful, rather than use a `for` loop with a range use a `while` loop with a decrement counter, the current value can then be modified during the loop eg

```py
while playerInput:
    # Decrement playerInput value
    playerInput -= 1
    cardDrawn = random.choice(card13)

    if cardDrawn == void:
        print("Your soul is sucked from your body. Draw no more cards")
        # Cannot draw more cards so decrement all to exit the loop
        playerInput = 0

    ...  # removed for brevity

    elif cardDrawn == jester:
        print("the card magically shuffles back into the deck.")
        # Increment the playerInput value as if the card wasn't drawn.
        playerInput += 1
```

A while loop will continue to loop until the condition is `True`, in Python an integer is considered `True` if it is non-zero allowing this to work.

Comment: Note that with this kind of loop, rather than using `return` or `break`, you could also just set `playerInput = 0`. That might be handy if you wanted to do something at the end of the loop in all cases.

Comment: @Blckknght quite likely in this use-case maybe the cards that were successfully drawn...